# Reading from a raw resource text file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to keep a .txt file in my res\raw file in Android Studio and read/parse the file.  I have a file "my_file.txt" in a folder called "raw" that I created in the "res" directory (that I didn't create).

Here's what I think my main issue is: When creating the File object (to use with the Scanner object), what path should I pass in for my text file?

Here's my code:

```
private void readFile(){
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("\\res\\raw\\my_file.txt"));  //I've also tried without the .txt extension
        Log.v("readFile->try","Trying to read file.");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Send error message.
    }
    if(scanner != null) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String[] line = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
            //Process string here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think you are looking for something along the lines of

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(res_id);
```

Where ctx is a instance of Context

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Tried it successfully. :)

Comment: For others looking at this, success came with the file in the "raw" folder that I created in the "res" directory.  I.e., ProjectName\app\src\main\res\raw\text_file.txt

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put it in `assets` folder under the `src/main` folder. Then you can use the `getAssets` method to retrieve the file like this

```
 InputStream in = (Activity)getContext().getAssets().open("my_file.txt")
```

If the folder does not exists, create one :-/

Comment: I tried testing this. For some reason this wasn't working in my app. First, the getContext() method wasn't recognized (I changed to getApplicationContext() ). Also, I'm getting an error by casting as an Activity and trying to store in an InputStream. Should that cast to an Activity be removed? It's beyond my understanding, so just brainstorming! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: ya, it depends on the place where you write the code, if you are writing inside a `Activity` then write just `getAssets().open("my_file.txt")`. If in a Fragment then `getActivity().getAssets().open("my_file.txt")`. If you are writing from someother place then you need to pass the activity as context and then cast it to activity. Depends on your usage

Answer (score 0):

or You can use this Function

```
private String readFile()
{
String myData = "";
File myExternalFile = new File("assets/","log.txt");
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        myData = myData + strLine + "\n";
    }
    br.close();
    in.close();
    fis.close();
 } catch (IOException e) 
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
   return myData;
}
```

just past in the path Location.