# Reading from a Text file in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

I have a class QuoteBank that needs to read in a txt file with scanner but it is giving me a file not found exception

java file is at
app/src/main/java/nate.marxBros/QuoteBank.java

txt file is at
app/src/main/assets/Quotes.txt

the code is

```
File file = new File("assets/QuotesMonkeyBusiness.txt");
    Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Shouldnt this work just like any other java program? but it gives file not found exception

I've tried many things on this site like 
[Android Studio Reading from Raw Resource Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634463/android-studio-reading-from-raw-resource-text-file)
but that method does not work because i dont know how to pass in Context

thanks for any help

updated code

```
public class QuoteBank {
private ArrayList<ArrayList<QuoteBank>> bank;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<QuoteQuestion> monkeyBuisness;


public QuoteBank(Context context){
    mContext = context;
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = mContext.getAssets().open("QuotesMonkeyBusiness.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<QuoteQuestion> monkeyBuisness = parseFileToBank(is);
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
QuoteBank b = new QuoteBank(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have a `MainActivity.java` or some `Activity` which instantiates `QuoteBank`. You would want the constructor to take in a parameter of context:

Setup a private variable in `QuoteBank.java`:

```
private Context mContext;
```

Setup up the constructor:

```
public QuoteBank(Context context) {
   this.mContext = context;
}
```

Then instantiate it in your activity,

```
QuoteBank quoteBank = new QuoteBank(context);
```

The context variable can be called within an activity by the `this` command or `Activity.this` where you replace "Activity" with your activity name. Alternatively if you are within a fragment, you can get the context from the `View` object inside your `onCreateView(...)` method. Usually by calling `view.getContext()`.

Now in your method where you are grabbing the assets, you can use the context:

```
InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open("QuotesMonkeyBusiness.txt")
```

Since you're using android studio you can either create a `main(String[] args) { ... }` method and run it or just start the emulator and have it use `Log.d(...)` to show output from the file.

Alternatively you can use the following method as well:

```
AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("QuotesMonkeyBusiness.txt");
```

It might also make sense to have `QuoteBank` as a singleton instance, that might increase efficiency although it all depends on your requirements, maybe something like:

```
List<String> allTextLines = QuoteBank.readFromFile(context, path_to_file);
```

And then in your `QuoteBank.java` class you can have a method like so:

```
/**
* Created by AndyRoid on 5/23/15.
*/
public class QuoteBank {

private Context mContext;

public QuoteBank(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

public List<String> readLine(String path) {
    List<String> mLines = new ArrayList<>();

    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();

    try {
        InputStream is = am.open(path);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            mLines.add(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mLines;
}
```

}

and then in my `MainActivity.java` class I have the following:

```
/**
 * Created by AndyRoid on 5/23/15.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String mPath = "adventur.txt";
private QuoteBank mQuoteBank;
private List<String> mLines;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mQuoteBank = new QuoteBank(this);
    mLines = mQuoteBank.readLine(mPath);
    for (String string : mLines)
        Log.d(TAG, string);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

This is the `adventur.txt` file I downloaded from a random database:

[image: file]

This is my log output:

[image]

---

**UPDATE: Why you should not use a Scanner in Android**

From the official documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html

> This class is not as useful as it might seem. It's very inefficient for communicating between machines; you should use JSON, protobufs, or even XML for that. Very simple uses might get away with split(String). For input from humans, the use of locale-specific regular expressions make it not only expensive but also somewhat unpredictable.
>   The Scanner class is not thread-safe.

---

**FINAL NOTE:**

I highly suggest you read up on the documentation of all the objects used here so you can understand the process.

Comment: Thanks the part about making a constructor helps. I still get a null pointer exception at  `AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();` i have context declared like `Activity context = new Activity();` in main activity and right before that line i have `this.mContext = context;`

Comment: and is there no way to do it with just entering a relative file location into file class? i feel like thatd be easier? Im not sure if inputStream will work with scanner .nextLine() methods

Comment: Instead of **Activity context = new Activity();** to grab the context, use the command **this** or **YOURACTIVITYNAME.this**. So it should look like **QuoteBank qb = new QuoteBank(this);** or **QuoteBank qb = new QuoteBank(YOURACTIVITYNAME.this);**

Assuming you didn't go the singleton route.

Comment: Okay, i updated my code above and it still gives null pointer at 'is = mContext.getAssets().open("QuotesMonkeyBusiness.txt");' it says at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:83)

Comment: I have it working properly on my android device, I'll update code

Comment: Out of curiosity, Is that adventure a Game or something? What is that actually?

Answer (score 3):

A simple Answer For A Simple Question.

```
private String readFile()
{
    String myData = "";
    File myExternalFile = new File("assets/","log.txt");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            myData = myData + strLine + "\n";
        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myData;
}
```

Just use the Function to Read a External File.

Answer (score 1):

`Context.getResources().getAssets().open("QuotesMonkeyBusiness.txt");` returns an `InputStream` the rest you can take it from there

**Edit**

> because i dont know how to pass in Context

`Context` is everywhere actually if you have a `View` you can get a `Context`, if you an `Activity` you can get `Context` so find it

Hope it helps