# Save an ArrayList<String> into internal storage

Tags: android, storage

I try to save an ArrayList of String in a txt file on the internal storage. (For some reason I can't use a SharedPreferences)

But, I don't know why it doesn't work. If I read the file in `onStop()` I can see the String I wanted to save, but if I quit the app and try to read just after in `onCreate()` the file is empty. But if I quit the app and go to `/data/data/myapp/file` I can see the file HiddenFormula.txt with the String I want in there.

Any idea ?

Here is the code I used to save and read the file :

```
public void saveHiddenFormulas(Context context, ArrayList<String> hiddenFormulas) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("HiddenFormulas.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        out.writeObject(hiddenFormulas);
        out.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static ArrayList<String> readSavedHiddenFormulas(Context context) {
    ArrayList<String> savedArrayList = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("HiddenFormulas.txt");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        savedArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return savedArrayList;
}
```

Comment: Well, I edit my post because the file is in my phone just after I quit the app.. I don't think that could be a caching issue

Comment: Could you edit this post and provide Activity code?

Answer (score 0):

May we see a stacktrace or where you called readSavedHiddenFormulas? I'll edit my answer when I get more info.

This link may help you: [Reading from a textfile in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417810/reading-from-a-text-file-in-android-studio-java)

Check out the answers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem but I don't know how. Now it seems to work... I think I changed the order of method call

Comment: Good to know its working for you. Try to take the time to understand how it suddenly worked out, it will help you later on. :)