# copied file text isn't readable

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that copies a file from memory (works) then reads it and displays information from the file. The file is in csv format and when I try to show textfrom the files all the the non english characters are shown like �. So itried opening it with Notepad ++ and i saw that when I try the UTF-8 encoding Notepad Shows the Characters that should be there suggesting it should be readable by the android app.
this is the code I used to copy the file:

```
//called in the main activity 
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    myIntent.setType("text/*");
    myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 100);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri result= data.getData();
            Log.e("fag", result.getPath() + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));

            copyFile(result);


        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e("", "canceled");
        }
    }
    Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(a);
}

 private void copyFile(Uri uri) {

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        out = openFileOutput(NAME , MODE_PRIVATE);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ( in.read(buffer) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.close();
        out = null;
    }  catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
        fnfe1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Then I display the file using a list view and read threw a buffer with this code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            File a = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + "/CSV_RAW");
            if(a.isFile())Log.e("TEST", "file exists");
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a.getPath()));
            int count = 0;
            String ln;
            while((ln =br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (ln.indexOf(',') != -1)
                    count++;
            }
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(a.getPath()));
            ln= br.readLine() ;
            arr = new String[count];
            count = 0;
            while((ln = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (ln.indexOf(',') != -1){
                arr[count] = getName(ln);
                count ++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I would like to know how to fix it or if there a deeper problem.

Comment: `�` usually means incorrect file encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from a Text file in Android Studio Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417810/reading-from-a-text-file-in-android-studio-java)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to write and read utf8 is to use [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)/[BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) with an [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)/[OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) like below

```
//reading utf8
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in /*your FileInoutStream*/ , "utf8"),1024 /* buffer size */);
//writing utf8
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out /*your FileOutputStream */, "utf8"),1024 /* buffer size */);
```